How to get all projects in the Active Collab API
I am trying to retrieve all projects with projects endpoint: https://myinstance/api/v1/projects but it only retrieves 100 projects (I have over 400). I searched on the API documentation, but I didn't see anything about pagination or something like that.
I tried:
GET https://myinstance/api/v1/projects


Same question was asked before, and answered. Here's a link:
ActiveCollab API return all active projects
